# Dataframe titles on to_csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of the following structure which I have simplified for the sake of this question, I am reading the dataframe from a csv file.

```
  A        B    C     D    E
  LOCATION DATE DATE  1    1
  LOCATION DATE DATE  1    1
  LOCATION DATE DATE  1    1
  LOCATION DATE DATE  1    1
```

I read in this csv from the file temp.dat using the following:

```
dfinal = pd.read_csv("temp.dat", header=0)
```

Then the following is done

```
os.remove("temp.dat")
dfinal = dfinal.sort_values(by="B", ascending=True)
f = open(t, "w")
f.write(stuff)
f.write(stuff)
dfinal.to_csv(t, index=False)
f.close()
```

In the above code the temp file is deleted, the dataframe is sorted by ascending date and then a new file whose name is assigned to `t` is opened. Then two lines
of metadata are written and the dataframe is written to the file and finally closed, however writing the dataframe as above produces errors on the column names like so.

As my file stands currently:

```
stuff
stuff
21,342,231,0,2 #Column names are being replaced here with unknown numbers
LOCATION DATE DATE  1    1
LOCATION DATE DATE  1    1
LOCATION DATE DATE  1    1
LOCATION DATE DATE  1    1
```

The column names are not printing correctly as the first line after the 2 "stuff" lines should be the header that is read from the csv temp.dat but the writing of the f.write statements are messing up the columns.

My desired output would be:

```
stuff
stuff
A        B    C     D    E
LOCATION DATE DATE  1    1
LOCATION DATE DATE  1    1
LOCATION DATE DATE  1    1
LOCATION DATE DATE  1    1
```

How would I go about achieving this?

Comment: Nope that does not solve it, what does the functionality of "a" do?

Comment: Yes, it was a bit complicated, please check answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `mode='a'` what means python write mode `append` in [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
print (dfinal)
          A      B     C  D  E
0  LOCATION  DATE1  DATE  1  1
1  LOCATION  DATE5  DATE  1  1
2  LOCATION   DATE  DATE  1  1
3  LOCATION   DATE  DATE  1  1

t = "temp.dat"
stuff = 'stuff\n'
dfinal = dfinal.sort_values(by="B", ascending=True)

#write metadata
with open(t, "w") as f:
    f.write(stuff)
    f.write(stuff)
#append df to existing file filled by metadata
dfinal.to_csv(t, index=False, mode='a')

#omit first 2 metadata rows
df = pd.read_csv(t, header=2)
print (df)
          A      B     C  D  E
0  LOCATION   DATE  DATE  1  1
1  LOCATION   DATE  DATE  1  1
2  LOCATION  DATE1  DATE  1  1
3  LOCATION  DATE5  DATE  1  1
```

Comment: Yep that solves it nicely thank you. Just one more question, what is the intended functionality of the with block?

Comment: It is universal solution for working with files in `with`, then close file function is handled properly. and is not necessary call it. But your solution works also.